# For radical polymerization reactions, azobis(isobutyronitrile) (AIBN) can also be used as a radical initiator

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, equilibrium, bond

Draw the mechanism of radical formation if you know that N2 is formed as a by-product.

[image]

The solution they give us is

[image]

I know what radical polymerization is. The free electron of a molecule binds with another molecule and creates a link. The second molecule will then have a free electron that will again bind with a third molecule. And this reaction will repeat.

But I'm a bit confused by their solution. How can I guess that N2 will form as a byproduct if they didn't tell us directly ? Also, do I understand correctly that a third electron link will be created with the two electrons that were previously bonded to the carbon atom ? At the end, we have N2 and the molecule in the second picture with a free electron. Do I understand correctly that when a molecule has a free electron like this, it is now a radical initiator ? So this molecule can later be used to start a polymerization process ?

I hope my question is clear. I'm a bit confused by those terms and would really appreciate your help. Thank you so much !

Comment: "I hope my question is clear." - as usually such comment signifies that clarity of the post leaves much to be wanted. Title in particular is hardly OK.

Comment: @Mithoron How should the title be changed ? That’s the same sentence as in the exercise they give us

Comment: Your question rambles a bit. When AIBN thermally cleaves the two C-N bonds homolytically, two stabilized radicals are formed as you have indicated. The other "product" is (unpaired electron)-N=N-(unpaired electron). The unpaired electrons are actually paired forming a $\pi$-bond of a molecule of nitrogen.

Comment: One question at a time would make it easier to formulate a meaningful title.

Comment: @user55119 This exercise seemed confusing to me. I just wonder how we can foresee that the two nitrogens will pair up if they don’t tell us. Feel free to post your comment as an answer if you want, I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: @user55119 If you have time, I have one more question: how can you know that the radicals are now stabilized ? On Google it says a stable radical has a low energy level, how can we know that in this context ? Do we just assume that because the exercise says so ?

Comment: Question 1: Unpaired electrons on vicinal atoms do not exist. They constitute a -bond. Q2: 1,1-diphenyl-2-picryl hydrazyl is a stable (isolable) free radical. (CH3)2CCN is a delocalized radical given the presence of the cyano group. Delocalized radicals are less reactive than, say, a methyl radical, which has no resonance stabilization.

Comment: @user55119 Thank you very much ! It makes more sense now. Feel free to post an answer if you want